# Laravel ajax file upload returns empty file value

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

When I try to upload a file through AJAX it returns this:

```
{_token: "kl7rG9Qj0ABggZdvlIo85VKwMy5ET7LS1IcumnVZ", invoice_file: {}}
```

The request does return `_token` so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Route:

```
Route::post('/invoices/recieved/upload/pdf', [App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceRecievedController::class, 'storePDFAsBase64'])->name('recieved.store.pdf');
```

Controller:

```
public function storePDFAsBase64(Request $request) {
    return response()->json($request->all());
}
```

HTML

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}" />
```

Added above meta tag in header

```
<form data-tab="1" id="step-1" action="{{ route('recieved.store.pdf') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
                
                <div class="space-y-6 sm:space-y-5">
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 items-start">
                        <div class="sm:col-span-1">
                            <label for="invoice_file" class="block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700 sm:mt-px sm:pt-2">
                                File<span class="text-red-500">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="mt-1">
                                <input type="file" name="invoice_file" id="invoice_file" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="border-t border-gray-200 mt-5"></div>
                <div class="mt-5 sm:mt-6  sm:grid sm:grid-cols-2 sm:gap-3 sm:grid-flow-row-dense">
                    <button type="submit" class="next_button w-full inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border-transparent shadow-sm px-4 py-2 {{ Auth::user()->company->settings->backgroundColor }} text-base font-medium text-white  focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 sm:col-start-2 sm:text-sm">Volgende</button>
                    <button type="button" id="hide_modal" class="mt-3 w-full inline-flex justify-center rounded-md border border-gray-300 shadow-sm px-4 py-2 bg-white text-base font-medium text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-50 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 sm:mt-0 sm:col-start-1 sm:text-sm">Sluiten</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

AJAX Post request:

```
$('#step-1').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let formData = new FormData(this);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: `/invoices/recieved/upload/pdf`,
            data: formData,
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            encode: true,
            success: function(response) {
                if (response) { console.log(response); }
            },
            error: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: How are you trying to get file from request? it should be like this ```$request->file('invoice_file')```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 10 months of leaving this alone I decided to dive in again and try to fix this issue. After many hours of pulling my hair out and frustratedly walking in and out of the room, I finally found the answer to my problem.

Ofcourse this code doesn't even return any file so it was kinda dumb to be even looking for it here.

```
return response()->json($request->all());
```

However, this also returned nothing:

```
return response()->json($request->file('file');
```

By accident I found out that

```
return $request->file('file');
```

returns the temporary path file.

After I found this, I came to the conclusion that `response()->json()` manipulates the file request and simply returns an empty object. So after 10 months I found that the problem lies in the json response and the actual return of the file itself works perfectly fine.

Worst developer ever.

Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this only for file:

```
if($request->hasFile('invoice_file')) {
        $file = $request->file('invoice_file');

        //you also need to keep file extension as well
        $name = $file->getClientOriginalName().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

        //using array instead of object
        $image['filePath'] = $name;
        $file->move(public_path().'/uploads/', $name);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This also returns {}